# Symfony2 - check if user has role at authentication

Tags: security, symfony, authentication

I could not find anything of this particular;

I need a simple check when a user login at the frontend, if this user has for example role: ROLE_CUSTOMER

I need this be done in the authenticationprocess, because it must return an error, if the user dont have this role.

Security.yml

```
    public:
        pattern:   ^/
        context:            site
        form_login:
            provider:       fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider:  form.csrf_provider   
            check_path:     site_login_check
            login_path:     site_login
            success_handler: authentication_handler
            failure_handler: authentication_handler                
        logout:
            path:           site_logout
            target:         site_login
        anonymous: true
```

Comment: What login method do you use? The [method from the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html)?

Comment: I use the FOSuserbundle

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think in this case you will have to write your own user provider, cause in FOSuserbundle assume the default ROLE is ROLE_USER and if the user doesn't have any, it will automatically associate it with the user and after the user is enabled FOS consider the user as valid login.
Or you need to specify your own login_check.

There is an other way, basically you make the assumption that FOSuser do the login and authentication and then you can create a service, call it successLoginHandler and after the user is "logged in" by fos, you can do your own stuff there and check for this role. If that's not exists you send back an access denied exception.

```
public function __construct($securityContext)
{
    $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
}

public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
{
    if(!$this->securityContext->isGranted('ROLE_CUSTOMER')){
        throw new \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Ill need to think about this.

Comment: Maybe if you explain a bit, why do you want to check for it -> Edited my answer. Maybe this can help.

Comment: Thanks Andras, Ill try in a few.. Why i want to check for it? Its maybe sort of "extra" i've all users in fos_user table, if for example a user with ROLE_ADMIN login at frontend (CUSTOMER), it will display a Access denied message after login.. So with this I can prevent..

Comment: What i would do in your case, i would not show a 403, but use only one firewall for frontend and backend, and if it has ROLE_ADMIN in the sucecsshandle, just simply redirect it to the admin interface. Please accept my answer then ;)

Comment: Hey Andras, thanks for your explanation, but both sides are seperated (Front and backend). and with seperated login forms. I hope you understand. :) Ill approve your answer